# 50s/60s Short story - Super-intelligent alien crash lands on Earth, looks like a sort of rabbit and ends up living with them

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story when I was 10 or 11 and found it very moving.

An alien from a very advanced species crashes on Earth. He is trying to communicate with humans to get help. He looks like a very cute furry animal, and no-one will pay him attention except to put him into some sort of travelling carnival sideshow, from which he escapes. The end is tragic...he goes to live with rabbits in a field.

The story might have been called something like 'The Star Creature'.

Comment: My first thought was *Quozl* from the title, but very different. :)

Comment: Reminds me of Harriet's Hare (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1168387.Harriet_s_Hare), though obviously that's from much later and at least one girl does listen to the alien.

Comment: Something about this is calling Theodore Sturgeon's name, but I can't find one of his stories that matches.

Comment: Thank you Zeiss Ikon.....I was about 12 when I read the story, and devoured every Victor Gollancz book I could fiind in the library (in the late 1960s.)  I know I read plenty of Theodore Sturgeon.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/238905/story-i-read-in-high-school-about-an-ape-like-alien-that-lands-on-earth-and-gets (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

I think I've found this one.  "[The Star Beast](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93803)" (1963) by Nicholas Stuart Gray.

It appears that the entire story can be read in a [Google Books preview](https://books.google.com/books?id=fDJoV9FdRKQC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=the+star+beast+nicholas+stuart+gray&source=bl&ots=gtAtH0mm8i&sig=ACfU3U3KI19bbDGkps39pYZFEevfrBlJ9w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2rMyUrqPrAhUMCM0KHYyhB-UQ6AEwCXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=the%20star%20beast%20nicholas%20stuart%20gray&f=false).

The creature falls from the sky, and shows up, hurt, at a farmer's door.  The authorities take it away but refuse to acknowledge its intelligence, so it gets sold to a circus.  As it gives up trying to communicate it gets increasingly treated like a dumb animal until it is finally broken.  The ending is indeed very sad:

> The last glimpse that anyone saw of it was by a hunter in the deeps of the forest.
>
> It was going slowly looking in terror at rabbits and squirrels.  It was weeping aloud and trying desperately to walk on all fours.

Comment: Funny that this is also the title of a well-known YA by Heinlein.